# How should I properly store passwords as a user?

Tags: security, passwords

So we all know that it's a bad idea to use one passwords for all your services.

A breach in just one service, could allow the hacker to access every one of your services that uses the same password. As a result, most people recommend that you use a different password for each service.

However, in the modern web, most super users have over a hundred different accounts, and it would be almost impossible to remember a unique password for each.

As a result, I have seen that a lot of people save all of their passwords in a text or excel file, which is also terribly insecure.

What would be the proper way to store passwords securely?

Comment: This is likely going to be closed because I only see an answer being written one of two ways.  A bunch of opinions or a bunch of software recommendations.  The only secure way I know to store passwords is to use a password manager, there are lots of options, use one that encrypts the data through the use of a master password.

Comment: So It's going to be closed because there isn't a right answer?

Comment: The purpose of my comment was to explain the reason I voted to close this question.  The question in my opinion sort of broad and the only way I could answer it is with a software recommendation which is a big warning flag.

Comment: This sounds more like best practice question too me. I find it potentially valuable, as I agree with the OP that password management is becoming increasingly difficult these days and I would be happy to know how other superusers tackle that. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Without enter in the password manager war (I recommend you to use one of them), I can propose you to make passwords algorithms. I'll give you an example:

**Algorithm**: xxX.f00_ZZZ-b4R.Yyy

```
(xxX=first 3 letters of the service
 Yyy=last 3 letters of the service
 ZZZ=number of letters of the service)
```

- **Amazon account**: amA.f00_6-b4r.Zon
- **Superuser account**: suP.f00_9-b4r.Ser
- (...)

Keep your algorithm safe and you will have multiple secure passwords and the ability to reconstruct them all.

Comment: And the service changes names... Or someone realizes this creates the same password for a service as anyone else using the service and this method, which means just one more line to add to their rainbow table. This is a good start, but it should contain something personal and private, relatively unique to the individual.

Comment: Of course it must be stronger, I'm giving an easy example of the method.

The problem of services changing their names isn't really a problem, you only need to change your pass in this service. Changing passwords is always a good (and bored) idea.

Comment: This sounds like you have zero bits of entropy? (although you've got that 6 and 9 in there that you didn't describe? I'm presuming it's the number of characters in the name) i.e. if someone gets your password, (because say, myfavoriteforum.com gets hacked, then it doesn't take much to discover all of your other passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following method:

1. You need to have some cloud storage space. Many cloud storage services exist, for example, [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) or [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/)
2. Choose a [strong password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) for your cloud storage account, and **memorize it**. An easy way to memorize a strong password is to memorize its pattern on a keyboard.
3. Create a [spreadsheet file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet) that contains all your passwords. Some cloud storage services have their own spreadsheet creation mechanisms, while others don't. If you choose one that doesn't supply you with the tools to create a spreadsheet, then you can use any [office suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_suite) to create it.
4. *Optional*: Add encryption and/or password protection to the spreadsheet file itself. Method varies depending on how you created it.
5. Log-in to your cloud storage and retrieve the password you need from the spreadsheet, either by opening it directly (if your cloud storage service has built-in spreadsheet viewer), or by downloading it to your device and opening it with a spreadsheet software.

This method's pros:

- No password protection software is needed.
- Easy to use and manage.
- You can store as many passwords as you like.
- You can add notes, dates or other information to your passwords.

Cons:

- Not automated.
- If your cloud storage account is compromised, that could also expose all your passwords.
- The storage account will become more sensitive due to the fact that it is storing all your passwords, hence it will be more difficult to use it with others (e.g., collaboratively).
- The method can be a bit tedious if the cloud storage you choose doesn't have a built-in spreadsheet viewer.